# How do I let skipped tests fail in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

When using jest in a circle ci environment, we discovered, that skipped tests won't fail with jest. So my Question is: Is there any way (like a config) to let jest fail if a test was skipped (test.todo was used)

We use jest version 24.7.1. 
I already tried to override the test.skip methods with the setupFiles flag, but then it says: test is not defined

Comment: Are you using ESLint? There is an ESLint plugin that you can use to check for skipped tests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest

Comment: The correct answer to your question would be no. the comment above is your best option IMO.

Comment: Skipped tests are marked "skipped" for a reason and should not trigger a "fail". The simplest solution to your problem would be to remove the "skipped" metadata and let them run.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It helped me(the ESLint thing)